# good practice for string.partition in python

Tags: python, string, variable-assignment

Sometime I write code like this:

```
a,temp,b = s.partition('-')
```

I just need to pick the first and 3rd elements. `temp` would never be used. Is there a better way to do this?

In other terms, is there a better way to pick distinct elements to make a new list?

For example, I want to make a new list using the elements `0,1,3,7` from the old list. The
code would be like this:

```
newlist = [oldlist[0],oldlist[1],oldlist[3],oldlist[7]]
```

It's pretty ugly, isn't it?

Comment: I don't see how you can make it prettier unless you want to write a function or rename oldlist to something shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Python's extended slicing feature to access a list periodically:

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> # Pick every other element in a starting from a[1]
>>> b = a[1::2]
>>> print b
>>> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Negative indexing works as you'd expect:

```
>>> c = a[-1::-2]
>>> print c
>>> [9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
```

For your case,

```
>>> a, b = s.partition('-')[::2]
```

Answer (score 8):

Be careful using

```
a, _, b = s.partition('-')
```

sometimes `_` is use for internationalization (gettext), so you wouldn't want to accidentally overwrite it.

Usually I would do this for `partition` rather than creating a variable I don't need

```
a, b = s.partition('-')[::2]
```

and this in the general case

```
from operator import itemgetter
ig0137 = itemgetter(0, 1, 3, 7)
newlist = ig0137(oldlist)
```

The itemgetter is more efficient than a list comprehension if you are using it in a loop

Comment: I like how this answers the actual question about efficiency, rather than simply providing alternative methods to call.

Answer (score 6):

For the first there's also this alternative:

```
a, b = s.partition('-')[::2]
```

For the latter, since there's no clear interval there is no way to do it too clean. But this might suit your needs:

```
newlist = [oldlist[k] for k in (0, 1, 3, 7)]
```

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) to understand the list slicing.

Comment: @user1544915: the first works by slicing the list with an interval of 2, so if you have a list like this: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` it will return: `[0, 2, 4]`. If you try `[::3]` it would return `[0, 3]`

Answer (score 2):

the common practice in Python to pick 1st and 3rd values is:

```
a, _, b = s.partition('-')
```

And to pick specified elements in a list you can do :

```
newlist = [oldlist[k] for k in (0, 1, 3, 7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to retain the middle field you can use `split` (and similarly `rsplit`) with the optional maxsplit parameter to limit the splits to the first (or last) match of the separator:

```
a, b = s.split('-', 1)
```

This avoids a throwaway temporary or additional slicing.

The only caveat is that with `split`, unlike `partition`, the original string is returned if the separator is not found. The attempt to unpack will fail as a result. The `partition` method always returns a 3-tuple.